# Scipy sparse matrix row broadcasing

Tags: python, scipy

I've been recently trying to do the following (efficiently)

1. Read a sparse (csr) matrix
2. Select a subset of rows
3. Construct another matrix (all zeros)
4. Fill 3. with the subset obtained in 2.

I can almost achieve this as follows:

```
input_matrix = scipy.io.loadmat(some_matrix)

random_indices = np.random.choice(input_matrix.shape[1], num_samples, replace=False)

second_matrix = sp.dok_matrix(input_matrix.shape)

## this takes up too much memory!
second_matrix[random_indices] = input_matrix[random_indices]
```

How does one do this more efficiently? I would not like to call .todense() at any point, as this would also explode in memory. Intuitively, one should be able to maybe mask a part of the matrix? In numpy (dense), I would simply fill the remainder with zeros, but for csr matrices I am not sure whether this is the way.

Thanks!

Comment: I've (at least partially) solved this using input_matrix.tolil(). Is this the way?

Comment: I think it would be better to use `random_indices` and `input_matrix` to construct the 3 input arrays for a `coo` style of definition.  At least a quick read of your problem suggests that should be fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks! This was the alternative solution indeed -- yet the lil format seems to capture the underlying structure well enough, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I testted .dok and .csr formats, yet the only format which does not result in space explosion is:

```
second_matrix[random_indices] = input_matrix.tolil()[random_indices]
```

Hence, the .lil matrix.

The suggestion by hpaulj also makes sense, yet I have yet to test it (lil works just fine for my task).